# Creating custom message and service for groovy, using them with Python

Tags: ros, python, service, rospy, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am discovering ROS groovy and I try to create a custom service. I followed the tutorial on creating a service with Python and did a Python node. But when I run my Python node, I get
'from myModuleName.srv import mysrv.srv
ImportError : no module named myModuleName'

I checked with rossrv that my service is known, I also tried to follow instructions in 'What's A Catkin?'

I don't know where to look for debug logs or build errors. What should I do ?

Thanks.

Manon

PS : the more I think of it, it does not look like the service is faulty, but Python can't find the right files to import.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54579/creating-custom-message-and-service-for-groovy,-using-them-with-python/) by [Manon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4153/manon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-09**:
Please update your question with a link to the tutorial you are following, so people will know what you are doing.

**Comment by [Manon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4153/manon/) on 2013-02-18**:
Well, I don't have enough karma to publish links. The tutorial for catkin is this one : http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/what and the python tutorial is the standard create a simple service and client in Python.

**Comment by [Manon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4153/manon/) on 2013-02-18**:
Thank you for your help. I will retry and let you know the result. The problem may be that when you click on a link on the tuto you go automatically to the rosmake version so I may have followed the wrong one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's an old question, but still a top hit on Google. So I'll post a possible solution:

First of all, as dornhege pointed out, your import statement is incorrect.  It should be:

```
from myModuleName.srv import mysrv
```

Also, have you sourced the setup.bash file in your catkin workspace? It should be at catkin_workspace_name/devel/setup.bash (where catkin_workspace_name is swapped with the name of your catkin workspace).  To source it:

```
source /path/path/path/catkin_workspace_name/devel/setup.bash
```

You can also add that line to your .bashrc file so that it's automatically sourced every time you open a terminal.

---

Originally posted by [Benjamin Blumer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3673/benjamin-blumer/) with karma: 287 on 2013-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akudoku](https://answers.ros.org/users/10646/akudoku/) on 2014-01-09**:
lubuntu 12.4
hydro

in almost same env, the solution makes me alive!
i spent a whole day to reset my project which copy the service and client example.
anyway, just doing 'source ~/CATKIN_WS/devel/setup.bash' solve this problem.

i'm so happy now.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like a python module that is called from other modules isn't generated, although I'm not sure since some info lacking (eg. which command you used to run your python module).

I suspect that you might have not followed creating `srv` tutorial. Make sure that in [CreatingMsgAndSrv](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_srv) tutorial page choose `catkin` at the TOP OF THE WIKI PAGE so that you will see necessary instruction (in this case adding macro to CMakeLists.txt etc.)

ps. I know this wiki pages structure isn't ideal...I just added clarification to wiki not to miss choosing right build system.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-02-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1